# Short story: Aliens come to Earth after humans uplifted them

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story that I read in an anthology book in the late 90s. The story itself had a feel of maybe being written in the 50s or 60s.

In the far future an expedition of aliens arrive at Earth. Their civilization was uplifted thousands of years ago by humanity. This was mostly on an agrarian level, in the vein of basic agricultural knowledge etc. Eventually the humans left and now, after finally developing space travel of their own, the aliens have come looking for their ancient benefactors.

They're disappointed to find that humanity has seemingly regressed - the cities are largely abandoned and everyone is living simple, rustic lives. There are still remnants of advanced technology, such as a suit worn by the human leader/representative that has gravity manipulation which allows him to hover/float/fly.

The human that meets them takes them on a tour of the abandoned cities and their lost marvels, seemingly bemused by the aliens' interest in these unimportant things. The aliens are disappointed that their many questions about how things work are frequently answered by "I've forgotten."

Eventually the aliens decide that they will need to bring in a full colonization effort and then round the humans up in reservations "for their own good," since humanity obviously needs their help to reclaim our former glory.

The human is against this idea, but the aliens' minds are made up. The human then snaps his fingers (figuratively) and the aliens abruptly find themselves and their entire expedition, starships included, back on the launch pad of their homeworld. They've been instantaneously transported across light years.

In the final scene, the alien captain and his head anthropologist meet in his cabin, where the anthropologist figures out what happened. Humanity has not regressed, but rather progressed so far that they've abandoned all of the "advanced" technology that is, to them, obsolete.

In his explanation he describes how a man from the modern era would have a hard time answering questions from a caveman. If asked how to light a fire using flint and tinder, most would be unable to answer, since such a method is just too primitive and they have forgotten the development.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is John W. Campbell's classic short story "[Forgetfulness](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48020)" (published under his Don A. Stuart penname) which matches your details perfectly.  It was first published in *Astounding Stories*, June 1937.

I could not find a copy online, but https://freeditorial.com/en/books/forgetfulness appears to allow downloads.

Here is the original question and matching extracts from the story.  OQ in bold, quotes as quotes as italics:

**In the far future an expedition of aliens arrive at Earth. Their civilization was uplifted thousands of years ago by humanity. This was mostly on an agrarian level, in the vein of basic agricultural knowledge etc. Eventually the humans left and now, after finally developing space travel of their own, the aliens have come looking for their ancient benefactors.**

*“Your people visited ours, once,” said Ron Thule softly. “There are legends, the golden gods that came to Pareeth, bringing gifts of fire and the bow and the hammer. The myths have endured through two millions of our years—four and a half millions of yours. With fire and bow and hammer my people climbed to civilization. With atomic power they blasted themselves back to the swamps. Four times they climbed, discovered the secret of the atom, and blasted themselves back to the swamps. Yet all the changes could not efface the thankfulness to the golden gods, who came when Pareeth was young.”*

*Seun nodded slowly. His unspoken thoughts formed clear and sharp in the astronomer’s mind. “Yes, I know. It was the city builders. Once, your sun and ours circled in a system as a double star. A wandering star crashed through that system, breaking it, and in the breaking making planets. Your sun circled away, the new-formed planets cooling; our Sun remained, these worlds cooling till the day life appeared. We are twin races, born of the same stellar birth. The city builders knew that, and sought your worlds. They were a hundred thousand light-years distant, in that time, across all the width of the galaxy, as the two suns circled in separate orbits about the mass of the galaxy.*

*“The city builders went to see your race but once. They had meant to return, but before the return was made they had interfered in the history of another race, helping them. For their reward the city builders were attacked by their own weapons, by their own pupils. Never again have we disturbed another race.”*

*They're disappointed to find that humanity has seemingly regressed - the cities are largely abandoned and everyone is living simple, rustic lives. There are still remnants of advanced technology, such as a suit worn by the human leader/representative that has gravity manipulation which allows him to hover/float/fly.*

*Three thousand feet they rose from the level of age-sifted soil at their bases, three thousand feet of mighty mass, stupendous buildings of the giants long dead.*

*Sheer, colossal mass, immeasurable weights and loading they were—and they seemed to float there on the grace of a line and a curve, half in the deep blue of the sky, half touching the warm, bright green of the land.
They floated still on the strength of a dream dreamed by a man dead these millions of years. A brain had dreamed in terms of lines and curves and sweeping planes, and the brain had built in terms of opal crystal and vast masses...they lived and floated still on the memory of a mighty glory. The glory of the race—*

*The race that lived in twenty-foot, rounded domes.*

**The human that meets them takes them of a tour of the abandoned cities and their lost marvels, seemingly bemused by the aliens' interest in these unimportant things. The aliens are disappointment that their many questions about how things work are frequently answered by "I've forgotten".**

*The engineers, Shor Nun, all stood frozen, watching him. Seun stopped, turned, half-smiling. “How? It is the lathan, the suit I wear.”*

*“It defies gravity?” asked Shor Nun, his dark eyes narrowing in keenest interest.*

*“Defies gravity? No, it does not defy, for gravity is a natural law. The city builders knew that. They made these suits shortly before they left the city. The lathan simply bends gravity to will. The mechanism is in the filaments of the back, servant to a wish. Its operation—I know only vague principles. I—I have forgotten so much. I will try to explain—”*

*Ron Thule felt the thoughts parading through his mind: Nodes and vibrations, atoms and less than atoms, a strange, invisible fabric of woven strains that were not there. His mind rebelled. Vague, inchoate stirrings of ideas that had no clarity; the thoughts were formless and indistinct, uncertain of themselves. They broke off.*

**Eventually the aliens decide that they will need to bring in a full colonization effort and then round the humans up in reservations "for their own good", since humanity obviously needs their help to reclaim our former glory.**

**The human is against this idea, but the aliens' minds are made up. The human then snaps his fingers (figuratively) and the aliens abruptly find themselves and their entire expedition, starships included, back on the launch pad of their homeworld. They've been instantaneously transported across light years.**

This is in the story pretty much as written in the question, but takes a couple pages -- too big to quote!

**In the final scene, the alien captain and his head anthropologist meet in his cabin, where the anthropologist figures out what happened. Humanity has not regressed, but rather progressed so far that they've abandoned all of the "advanced" technology that is, to them, obsolete.**

**In his explanation he describes how a man from the modern era would have a hard time answering questions from a caveman. If asked how to light a fire using flint and tinder, most would be unable to answer, since such a method is just too primitive and they have forgotten the development.**

*“What are these people of Rhth?”*

*Ron Thule’s voice was a whisper from the darkness. “I come from a far world, by what strange freak we will not say. I am a savage, a rising race that has not learned the secret of fire, nor bow, nor hammer. Tell me, Shor Nun, what is the nature of the two dry sticks I must rub, that fire may be born? Must they be hard, tough oak, or should one be a soft, resinous bit of pine? Tell me how I may make fire.”*

*“Why—with matches or a heat ray—No, Ron Thule. Vague thoughts, meaningless ideas and unclear. I—I have forgotten the ten thousand generations of development. I cannot retreat to a level you, savage of an untrained world, would understand. I—I have forgotten.”*

*“Then tell me, how I must hold the flint, and where must I press with a bit of deer horn that the chips shall fly small and even, so that the knife will be sharp and kill my prey for me? And how shall I rub and wash and treat the wood of the bow, or the skin of the slain animal that I may have a coat that will not be stiff, but soft and pliable?”*

*“Those, too, I have forgotten. Those are unnecessary things. I cannot help you, savage. I would greet you, and show you the relics of our deserted past in museums. I might conduct you through ancient caves, where mighty rock walls defended my ancestors against the wild things they could not control.*

*“Yes, Ron Thule. I have forgotten the development.”*

*“Once”—Ron Thule’s voice was tense—“the city builders made atomic generators to release the energy bound in that violent twist of space called an atom. He made the sorgan to distribute its power to his clumsy shells of metal and crystal—the caves that protected him from the wild things of space.*

*“Seun has forgotten the atom; he thinks in terms of space. The powers of space are at his direct command. He created the crystal that brought us here from the energy of space, because it made easy a task his mind alone could have done. It was no more needful than is an adding machine. His people have no ships; they are anywhere in space they will without such things. Seun is not a decadent son of the city builders. His people never forgot the dream that built the city. But it was a dream of childhood, and his people were children then. Like a child with his broomstick horse, the mind alone was not enough for thought; the city builders, just as ourselves, needed something of a solid metal and crystal, to make their dreams tangible.”*

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is a match?

Comment: Short of listing each detail in the question and saying "Match", it's pretty hard.  The original question was a very accurate listing of the story's main points even down to the bit about the flint.

Comment: No mention of flint, but you could probably mine https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174098/scifi-short-story-planet-with-great-abandoned-cities-simple-natives-with-mind/174101#174101 for quotes and summary.

Comment: @MarkOlson - That comment would improve the answer, as would adding in any quotes you can grab from that copy you've found online

Comment: @Valorum OK, I can do that.  As it happens, I was involved in the NESFA Press Campbell collection and have the sources.  They are not PD so I can't post the whole text,  but I can pull quotes.  It will take some time, though.

Comment: Yes, this is it, thank you! I particularly remember the line "I have forgotten the development."I checked the Freeditorial link and the pdf version there matches my recollection perfectly. Thank you again.

Comment: @MarkOlson Out of curiosity, why are works from the 1930s not in the public domain yet?

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica There is only one answer to copyright questions: "Well, it's complicated."  My go-to is the Cornell Libraries Copyright table: https://guides.library.cornell.edu/copyright/publicdomain.  "Forgetfulness" falls under "1927 through 1963 -- Published with notice and the copyright was renewed: expires 95 years after publication date" I don't know for sure that copyright was renewed, but as of 20 years ago, the Campbell Estate was still being actively represented.

Comment: @MarkOlson Thanks. Such long copyrights seem wrong -- unless they are your source of income, I presume ;-).